# How can Restore MS SQL 2000 database To Ms SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server

Please suggest:
I have MS SQL 2000 database  backup i want to Restore in Ms SQL 2012 Please suggest.

Comment: See [This Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2012/06/15/migration-sql-server-2000-to-sql-server-2012/)

Answer (score 2):

You must first restore the 2000 database to a SQL Server 2005 instance, then take a backup from the 2005 instance to restore on the 2012 instance.